# Ошибка в приложении Android при изменении текста TextView, нажатием на кнопку

Tags: android

Код в MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    private TextView helloTv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        TextView helloTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_tv);
        Button helloBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hello_btn);
        helloBtn.setOnClickListener(OnClickListener);
    }

    private  final View.OnClickListener OnClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
          helloTv.setText("stackoverflow.com");
        }
    };
}
```

xls:

```
  <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hello_tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello, world!"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/hello_btn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click me!"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: переменная метода не доступна в внутреннем классе. вам нужно объявить helloTv полем класса (убрать TextView перед объявлением переменной в методе `onCreate()`): `helloTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_tv);` иначе вы указываете локальную переменную с таким же именем, как поле класса. она не доступна вне метода, а поле класса остается не инициализированным (null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хоть конкретно об ошибке не сказано. Надеюсь уточним.

Вот здесь `TextView` явно лишнее. Вы же объявили уже эту переменную

```
TextView helloTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_tv);
```

сделайте так

```
helloTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello_tv);
```

Comment: Точно. Спасибо большое, я и не заметила